# Heroku Socket.IO server connection refused from Cocos2D app

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io, cocos2d-x

I'm having an issue connecting my Cocos2D application to a Socket.IO server hosted on Heroku. Using my the Cocos2D Socket.IO client I attempt to connect to `***.herokuapp.com:80` and am greeted with this output:

```
In the constructor of HttpClient!
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
cocos2d: QuadCommand: resizing index size from [-1] to [2560]
[WebSocket::init] _host: ***.herokuapp.com, _port: 80, _path: /socket.io/1/websocket/?EIO=2&transport=websocket&sid=GhYgtb7djoMU4u79AAAB
WebSocket thread start, helper instance: 0x6000000a2ee0
NOTICE: Initial logging level 967

NOTICE: Libwebsockets version: 1.6.0 3ca4bac

NOTICE: IPV6 compiled in and enabled

NOTICE: libev support not compiled in

NOTICE:  mem: platform fd map: 38912 bytes

NOTICE:  mem: per-conn:          336 bytes + protocol rx buf

WebSocket (0x6000001c2fd0) onConnectionError ...
Ready state is closing or was closed, code=2, quit websocket thread!
NOTICE: lws_context_destroy

WebSocket (0x6000001c2fd0) onConnectionClosed ...
WebSocket thread exit, helper instance: 0x6000000a2ee0
Websocket error received: 1
In the destructor of WebSocket (0x6000001c2fd0)
```

Im not sure what to make of this, and have searched everywhere for a solution. I have tried changing the port to `:443` and am given this:

```
In the constructor of HttpClient!
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
cocos2d: QuadCommand: resizing index size from [-1] to [2560]
SIOClientImpl::handshake() failed
error buffer: Empty reply from server
```

I'm not really sure what to make of this. If I try connecting to the same Socket.IO server through `localhost:3000` It works just fine, and I revieve all events no problem. How can I fix this? Is this a Heroku issue? Am I just using the wrong URL?